# os.path.join accesses file preventing rename operation

Tags: python, io, path

I am trying to handle a JSON decode by backing up a malformed file when the decode fails, but I'm experiencing some strange behaviour that I did not expect from the `os.path.join` method.

The following code fails with an exception: `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'file.txt' -> 'file.txt\\.bak'`

```
file_path = "file.txt"

try:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        json.load(f)

except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    os.rename(file_path, os.path.join(file_path, '.bak'))
```

If I change the argument like this: `os.rename(file_path, file_path + '.bak')` The code executes as expected without the permission error. It seems like the `os.path.join` method actually accesses the file rather than being a strict string operation. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.join(file_path, '.bak'))` actually will give you `file.txt\\.bak` like you see in the error code, but `file_path + '.bak'` gives you the correct file name `file.txt.bak`

[os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) appends a separator between it's arguments, hence it ends up adding that separator in your case too

Example in MacOS, you can see that it adds a separator between each of it's arguments. os.path.join is more useful to append directory names, of the full filename with the directory paths.

```
In [4]: import os                                                                                                                                                                 

In [5]: os.path.join('filename','.bak')                                                                                                                                           
Out[5]: 'filename/.bak'

In [6]: os.path.join('folder1', 'folder2')                                                                                                                                        
Out[6]: 'folder1/folder2'
```

The error happens since the Windows OS is trying to make a file `.bak` in a folder named `file.txt`, which isn't possible since file.txt is a plain file and not a directory, which is correct.

Using `file_path+'.bak` creates the `file.path.bak` correctly in the folder you want, hence you don't see an error there!

Comment: I forgot about the separators, that's a good catch. Does it explain why a Permission error is generated though?

Comment: That's because we don't have a folder called `file.txt` where you are trying to create a `bak` file @Alex I have updated my answer with the reason :)

Comment: Makes sense I guess, the error message is somewhat misleading

Comment: Cool @Alex I have updated my answer with the reason as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is the key. As usually on Windows  the cause (*because it is being used by another process*) is wrong, but the names (*'file.txt' -> 'file.txt\.bak'*) are correct.

Join is not a string concatenation but expects that all path members except the last represent folders. So here you are trying to make a file `.bak` in a **folder** named `file.txt`. It is not possible because `file.txt` is a plain file and not a directory.

On another hand, when you use `os.rename(file_path, file_path + '.bak')` you are renaming `file.txt` to `file.txt.bak` in the same folder which is allowed by the underlying file system, hence no error.

So the behaviour is exactly what is expected, except for the beginning of the error message.

---

As I am not a core Microsoft Developper, the following is a wild guess. The number of error given by the system is limited. The rename C function received 2 strings and passed it to the system call for rename. As expected the file system generated an error but as it was neither a physical error nor a file system full error, it just choosed a *permission refused* cause. Which is not really wrong because it is not allowed to create folders under a plain file. But the message for that error is unfortunately *because it is being used by another process* which is stupid here

Comment: So the error is because it is trying to rename a file into a directory and the error messages are wonky?